# get top 5 frequent values and their total count Linq-to-Sql

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql

i am using this Linq to sql to get most appearing records.

```
List<int> result;
result = await context.InvoiceItems.GroupBy(q => q.ProductID)
        .OrderByDescending(gp => gp.Count())
        .Take(5)
        .Select(g => g.Key).ToListAsync();
```

and getting int type values. but i want also to get total number of times each value is occurred. like this SQL query is returning.

```
select productID, Count(*) AS value_occurrence from InvoiceItems group by productID
```

see this table image

[image: SQL results]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to group by `ProductID` and then project your result into `Sample` class, one property with `.Key` and second property with `.Count()`.

```
List<Sample> result = await context.InvoiceItems.GroupBy(q => q.ProductID)
                  .OrderByDescending(gp => gp.Count())
                  .Take(5)
                  .Select(g => new Sample { ProductID = g.Key, Value_Occurence = g.Count() }).ToListAsync();

result.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine($"ID: {x.ProductID}, \t Value_Occurence: {x.Value_Occurence}"));
```

You can project your result into below sample class.

```
class Sample
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public int Value_Occurence { get; set; }
}
```

**Output:** Input with only one `InvoiceItem` for each of productID.

[image]

Comment: what will be the type of result instead of var ?

Comment: @Hammas_stack1, answer update and now the type of result is `List<Sample>`

Comment: @Hammas_stack1, before update the type of `result` is anonymous type